# Form for Uploading Files to Web Server

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a form inside a PHP file that will allow me to type in a couple text fields and then upload those fields to certain tables/columns in my database. I can figure this out, but another option I want is to upload a song and upload an image to my webserver and then retrieve the link and upload those links to the database..

Does anyone know of a good tutorial for this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I have successfully implemented this: http://teamtutorials.com/web-development-tutorials/php-tutorials/inserting-data-into-a-mysql-database-using-php

Comment: But I am stuck on how to upload a file and then retrieve that same file's URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find information on the php page.
Here is the link for upolading files information.
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php